# Create a SSH key (or token) with permission on one repository only, with Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, ssh-keys

I'm working with a Azure DevOps repository, and I have a question but I cannot find any information about if it's possible.

I want to have a server who auto-check and auto-deploy some web changes. For this, I'll be using cron with git pull.

The question are, ¿How can I authorize the server to do a git pull, but only with permission on the repository who have the information?
I understand leaving a SSH key on a server can be risky, or a hard-coded token. That's because I want the server to have a authentication method to the repository who only have permission on these repository and not all of them (I have more than 10 repositories on devops).

I know a method is to have a user who can login on DevOps with permission only on these project. But I want some "more administrator-friendly" method.

NOTE: I don't know if it's possible or not, the question itself is a search of knowledge.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create an OAuth App and control its scopes or create a dedicated user in Azure DevOps to limit the security permissions of that user and generate a PAT for that.

The [OAuth flow is quite a process, too much to capture in this answer](https://blog.lionpham.com/en/2021/03/21/oauth-2-authentication-azure-devops-automation/).

Or use the [Device Profile option](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/DeviceProfileSample).

Comment: The dedicated user option are the easy one, and are one of the options I've told myself on the question. OAuth problem are the login itself, the login cookie gets invalid after some period (Any azure app uses OAuth and API, and the login have a determinate duration). Then, my conclusion are, separate of the dedicated user, devops doesn't have these feature.

Comment: The OAuth token can be renewed with the refresh token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#refresh-an-expired-access-token

Comment: That's great then, I'll try this option. Thanks.